# HTML5 Local Storage - Creating and writing to a json file?

Tags: html, activex, client-side, logging, local-storage

We are building a web application using SVG & JS. The log file for this application needs to be created on the client side and then finally uploaded to the server once the project is ended.

As we donot wish to go near ActiveX controls, is it possible to achieve this with the new HTML5 'Local Storage'? Isnt that what 'Local Storage' is for anyways?

Is there a working example of this as well?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by this but there is something out there called [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).
It uses javascript and json to save data to the local database.

Comment: Gerard, thanks! Thats a great start. I'll look into this on the pronto. Best,